# how to solve the error in this json in elastic search?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, jupyter-notebook

I need to calculate the most common interests into the employees

The json it is something like:

```
{"index":{"_index":"companydatabase"}}  
 {"FirstName":"ELVA","LastName":"RECHKEMMER","Designation":"CEO","Salary":"154000","DateOfJoining":"1993-01-11","Address":"8417 Blue Spring St. Port Orange, FL 32127","Gender":"Female","Age":62,"MaritalStatus":"Unmarried","Interests":["Body Building","Illusion","Protesting","Taxidermy","TV watching","Cartooning","Skateboarding"]}
{"index":{"_index":"companydatabase"}}  
 {"FirstName":"JENNEFER","LastName":"WENIG","Designation":"President","Salary":"110000","DateOfJoining":"2013-02-07","Address":"16 Manor Station Court Huntsville, AL 35803","Gender":"Female","Age":45,"MaritalStatus":"Unmarried","Interests":["String Figures","Working on cars","Button Collecting","Surf Fishing"]}
{"index":{"_index":"companydatabase"}}
```

I write:

```
request_body = {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "interests": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Interests",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
JSON(es.search(index="companydatabase", body=request_body))
```

but the Jupiter notebook return me this error

```
RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [Interests] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory.')
```

the error it is in the last line

thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using the default mapping for your Elasticsearch index ie (Elasticsearch generated the mapping for your index),

And you are using the `terms` aggs on `text` field which is not supported by default, what you can do is just use

```
request_body = {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "interests": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Interests.keyword", --> note here
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It should work if your mapping is generated by Elasticsearch.

Refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html and for more info.

[image]

Comment: but if I put the same last line "JSON(es.search(index="companydatabase", body=request_body))" the code return me: "TransportError: TransportError(500, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'Invalid aggregation order path [count]. The provided aggregation [count] either does not exist, or is a pipeline aggregation and cannot be used to sort the buckets.')"

Comment: @NadieN you don't need extra `order` as `terms` bucket aggs already sorts the bucket based on the document counts.